# Message: Call to undefined method CI_Email::get_emails() codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter-3

I try build function in controller Codeigniter 3 to read emails from inbox and insert to database.

```
`public function read_emails() {
  // Load the email and database libraries
  $this->load->library('email');

  // Connect to the POP3 server
  $config = array(
    'protocol' => 'pop3',
    'pop3_host' => 'pop.gmail.com',
    'pop3_user' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'pop3_pass' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'pop3_port' => 995,
    'pop3_encryption' => 'ssl'
  );
  $this->email->initialize($config);

  // Retrieve emails from the inbox
  $emails = $this->email->get_emails();

  // Loop through the emails
  foreach ($emails as $email) {
    // Check if the email was received within the last 24 hours
    $received_time = strtotime($email['received_time']);
    $current_time = time();
    if ($current_time - $received_time <= 86400) {
      // Check if the email already exists in the database
      $this->db->where('email', $email['email']);
      $query = $this->db->get('contacts');
      if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {
        // Insert the email into the database
        $data = array(
          'email' => $email['email'],
          'subject' => $email['subject'],
          'message' => $email['message']
        );
        $this->db->insert('contacts', $data);
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

When I run this controller I get output:
`Message: Call to undefined method CI_Email::get_emails()`

Can anyone please help me debug this issue? Very important.

line 43:

```
  // Retrieve emails from the inbox
  $emails = $this->email->get_emails();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if codeigniter3's email class has such a get_emails() function, or if you can retrieve emails from the inbox.

Please check the official documentation: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/email.html

If it is a custom class/plugin/addon, you should either publish its code or submit a link to the repo

Comment: it is not a solution to a problem avoid discussions on answers, if you have something to discuss use comments instead of giving answers.Please [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)